# Centos gcc incompatible libm.so and libc.so

Tags: gcc, g++, centos, libc, libm

Trying to get a c++ program to compile on Centos 6.3. Running into the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libm.so when searching for -lm
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc
```

when using the command:

```
g++ -L /usr/lib newcode2.cpp -lusb-1.0 -o newcode2
```

which has consistently working all day.

the system has /lib/libc.so.6 and some posts lead me to believe a partial solution may be a symbolic link. gcc version is 4.4.7. ldconfig -v did not show libc.so just libc.so.6. I tried to move the /usr/lib/libc.so and libm.so to _old. After that just created the two links below:

```
ln -s /lib/libc.so.c /usr/lib/libc.so 
ln -s /lib/libm.so.c /usr/lib/libm.so
```

did not solve it. I have the same two messages from the compiler.

Comment: Please post the actual g++ command line.

Comment: Thank you stark. This has been working all day and appeared to stop when I started with this new version of code I was compiling:  g++ -L /usr/lib newcode2.cpp -lusb-1.0 -o newcode2
... you got me to look at this very carefully and it was in fact the -L option which just needed to be removed. I'm so grateful! ps: added to original question to improve readability. =0)